# connecting samsung smart tv to Eclipse SDK console

Tags: eclipse, samsung-smart-tv

When testing apps on the tv it should return data to the console in my eclipse SDK,

The app is synced on the TV from my workstation, via a xampp server
The log Reciever is turned on on my workstation,
The IP settings on the TV are set to my workstation,
The TV is in developer mode.

But when running the app on the TV it does not trigger any message,
Anyone any idea where to look for adjusting settings, ports recieving or anything?

Comment: Did you turn on 'Samsung Smart TV Log Receiver' in Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Which TV are you testing on? There were issues with some 2012 bd/tv models not sending the logs. Then yes turn on the log receiver in Eclipse.

Can you see the logs in Eclipse if you run the app from the Emulator?